# Structuring several million records across multiple files in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, bigdata, analytics

Several csv files collectively holding millions of lines (approx 6 million )will be created every 30 seconds. The csv basically has Timestamp, Id1, Id2 , values....

I want to construct a folder structure that looks like
timestamp/id1/id2/ in HDFS within the 30 second interval. (Which means I will have to shuffle the 6million lines and write lines with same ids into one file)

Atm I tried using spark to arrange the records, but writing these records into HDFS takes considerable time.

Comment: Is it actually necessary for you to process them in real-time?

Comment: Hi Glennie, Should process it before the next batch comes in after 30 seconds.

Comment: Why not to use HBase for your purposes instead of folder structure?